# How using @InsertOnlyProperty with Spring Boot 2.7

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I'm going to use *@InsertOnlyProperty* with Spring Boot 2.7 as it will take time for us to migrate to Spring Boot 3.0!
So I'm going to create my *DataAccessStrategy* based on the *DefaultAccessStrategy* and also override the *SqlParametersFactory* so that I can pass the *RelationalPersistentProperty::isInsertOnly* condition to the *getParameterSource* method, also overriding *RelationalPersistentProperty* by adding *isInsertOnly*. And is there a way to override RelationalPersistentProperty to add *isInsertOnly* property. Am I correct or is there a better solution than switching to Spring Boot 3.0 now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since `@InsertOnlyProperty` is only supported for the aggregate root (in Spring Boot 3.0), one approach could be to copy the data to a surrogate object and use a custom method to save it. It would look something like this:

```
public record MyAggRoot(@Id Long id, 
  /* @InsertOnlyProperty */ Instant createdAt, int otherField) {}

public interface MyAggRootRepository 
  extends Repository<MyAggRoot, Long>, MyAggRootRepositoryCustom { /* ... */ }

public interface MyAggRootRepositoryCustom {
  MyAggRoot save(MyAggRoot aggRoot);
}

@Component
public class MyAggRootRepositoryCustomImpl implements TaskRepositoryCustom {
  @Autowired 
  private final JdbcAggregateOperations jao;
  
  // Override table name which would otherwise be derived from the class name
  @Table("my_agg_root") 
  private record MyAggRootForUpdate(@Id Long id, int otherField) {}
 
  @Override
  public MyAggRoot save(MyAggRoot aggRoot) {
     // If this is a new instance, insert as-is
     if (aggRoot.id() == null) return jao.save(aggRoot);

     // Create a copy without the insert-only field
     var copy = new MyAggRootForUpdate(aggRoot.id(), aggRoot.otherField());
     jao.update(copy);
     return aggRoot;
  }
}
```

It is however a bit verbose so it would only be a reasonable solution if you only need it in a few places.